# How to return actual file data instead of file URL from Django Rest Framework FileField object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a simple API that returns XML file data to the client. I am using Django 3.0.4 and Django Rest Framework 3.11.0 and have based most of my work on this tutorial https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

This is my model:

from django.db import models

```
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    device = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "API"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

This is the views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import FileSerializer
from .models import File

class FileList(APIView):
    """
    List all files, or create a new file.
    """
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        files = File.objects.all()
        serializer = FileSerializer(files, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class FileDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a file instance.
    """

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        file = File.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = FileSerializer(file)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is the App URLs:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import FileList
from .views import FileDetail
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:pk>', FileDetail.as_view()),
    path('', FileList.as_view()),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have this in SETTINGS:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/path/to/file:devices/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "path/to/file:devices")
```

Everything works well, I do not see any errors. I am able to POST a file and GET files (either as a list or as an individual file, based on pk) using Postman.
The problem I have is that when I GET an individual file I get this:

```
{
    "file": "/path/to/file:devices/example.xml",
    "device": "example.xml"
}
```

I want the response to be the file contents (actual XML data) not the URL to the file.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured this out for myself. Pretty simple really.

All I had to do was redirect the GET to the URL of where the actual file is stored in the file structure.

Here is the new FileDetail class view:

```
class FileDetail(APIView):
    """
    Get or delete a file instance.
    """

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        print("hitting detail get")
        response = redirect(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, (pk +'.xml')))
        return response
```